# There is no Blank Activity option in Android Studio 2.0 to create that

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-studio-2.0

I Created a project using Android Studio 2.0 ,and now i want to create a blank activity ,  but there is no  "Blank Activity"  item in 
 ( Right-Click on project package and then --> New -> Activity ) sub-menu.

when i click on ( New -> Activity -> Gallery... ) i meet a window without "Blank Activity" Option like this.
[New -> Activity -> Gallery...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oFlv.png)

i only want to have an activity like this 
[Activity with 3-dot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwPeR.png)

Comment: so make one manually

Comment: File > New > Java class. Make it extend some variant of `Activity`. Add it to the Manifest.

Comment: thank you for answer , i do not want to make it manually i want to make my job easier if it possible

Answer (score 4):

The "Basic Activity" template probably is the closest match to the former "Blank Activity".

That being said:

- Google is welcome to change templates at any time. Please do not assume that templates with magic names, like "Blank Activity", always will exist.
- Whether this makes your job "easier" depends entirely upon what you think of Google's activity templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Activity, just edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Just change the default `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"`.